# Как создавать статью от лица пользователя

Tags: javascript, node.js, auth

Хочу реализовать на сайте возможность авторизации. Допустим, можно создать свою статью, но только при условии, что пользователь авторизован.

Так вот, как реализовать саму авторизацию. Можно хранить на backend'е спец. ключ, подтверждающий авторизацию, но как тогда узнать, что пользователю можно выдать этот ключ?

У меня есть идея:

Отправить пользователю на email письмо с подтверждением и, когда будет обработан переход по ссылке, отправлять пользователю спец. ключ.

Вот только как это сделать? При подтверждении с письма, общение идет с письмом, а не с клиентом. Как можно при отправке письма отправлять спец. ключ? Или, возможно, есть более правильный способ. Мне нужен алгоритм и способ реализации.

Comment: Чем обычные способы авторизации не подходят? Не понятно зачем email, если пользователь при авторизации автоматически авторизован уже.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev, Как выглядит мой способ целиком: на сервер отправляется запрос, он содержит email пользователя. На email отправляется подтверждающее письмо. При переходе по ссылке пользователь становится активным. Вот только 1) Как об этом сообщить на клиент. 2) Как сделать это с условием безопасности. По поводу второго более-менее понятно - отправить спец. код, который каждый раз будет представляться серверу. Вот и мой вопрос.

Comment: На клиент не нужно ничего сообщать. Если человек перешёл по сcылке с ключом, то открывается браузер с его аккаунтом, уже авторизованный. После этого сервер у себя должен удалить этот ключ, чтобы им не воспользовались повторно. А следующие разы уже по логину и паролю будет вход. Тут у вас просто смешана авторизация и подтверждение почты сразу. Их можно разделить например, чтобы подтверждение было уже потом в аккаунте.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev, это почти то, что мне нужно. В моем случае я бы хотел реализовать авторизацию только по email, как например на [avacode](https://avocode.com/)

Comment: Там не только по email, но ещё есть кнопка логина и есть ввод пароля при регистрации. Если сделать только по почте, то будет не удобно постоянно в неё лазить, не у всех она доступна всегда в один клик.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev, понятно, спасибо за объяснение